# jQuery UI Droppable: How to make elements more greedy?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am having a problem with nested droppable elements using jQuery UI.

Here's the background:

I have a parent droppable element which has child droppable elements that arranged next to each other. I also have a set of draggable elements to be dragged onto the droppable elements.

```
<div class="droppable container">
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
        <div class="droppable">
        </div>
</div>

<aside>
    <div class="draggable"></div>
    <div class="draggable"></div>
    <div class="draggable"></div>
    <div class="draggable"></div>
</aside>
```

The droppable elements have the `greedy` property set to `true`, which should theoretically prevent propagation to parent elements. The problem is that this works inconsistently. Sometimes the parent gets activated along with the child. This seems to happen most when you drag from one child to an adjacent child.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I tried. Try dragging the blue squares into the various pink drop-zones. You'll notice sometimes the parent lights up, even though there is no space between the child elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/kXnAM/7/

Comment: The drop's `greedy` is working fine. It's the `hoverClass` that is not being "greedy", if you will.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the browser acts like there is enough space between the child divs that it fires the drag event for the parent div.  However, this happens so fast that the parent class can at some points get stuck on the hovered state.  Here is an example of using the `dropover` event to remove the hovered class from the container div: http://jsfiddle.net/vE5QK/

```
$(".child").on("dropover", function(event, ui) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.container').removeClass('hovered');     
    }, 1);
});
```

I use the timeout as otherwise the timing can conflict with the other events.  This isn't perfect as you will sometimes see the parent flash the hovered state if you drag quickly, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: The link points to the original version, can you repost the link? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I also tried achieving the same thing without jquery-ui, and it seems to work much more cleanly now. Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/kXnAM/11/

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's best to handle something yourself and not rely on internal library magic.  Good to see you got it working.